# I'm having trouble with the logic I'm using and the syntax required

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that I need to calculate some formulas with `DATETIME` and `DECIMAL(10,2)` that are in the table, so far I got this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DEPRE]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @FechaReg DATETIME = (SELECT Fec_ActivoDep FROM Dep_Act),
        @Fechahoy DATETIME = (SELECT GETDATE()),
        @MESES DATETIME,
        @Utililidad1 DECIMAL(10,2),
        @Utilidad2 DECIMAL(10,2),
        @IVA1 DECIMAL(10,2),
        @IVA2 DECIMAL(10,2),
        @Deprec1 DECIMAL(10,2),
        @Deprec2 DECIMAL(10,2),
        @Inversion1 DECIMAL(10,2),
        @Inversion2 DECIMAL(10,2),
        @Total DECIMAL(10,2),
        @Contador INT;

     SET @Fechahoy = (SELECT GETDATE());
     SET @FechaReg = (SELECT Fec_ActivoDep FROM Dep_Act);
     SET @MESES = (DATEDIFF(month, @FechaReg, @Fechahoy));

    SET @Utililidad1 = (0.08);
    SET @IVA1 = (0.16);

    SET @Inversion1 = (SELECT Dbl_MontoInv FROM Dep_Act);
    SET @Deprec1 = ((SELECT Dbl_MontoInv*(0.10) FROM Dep_Act));
    SET @Deprec2 = (SELECT(((@Inversion1) * ((((@Deprec1) / (12)) * ((SELECT CAST (@MESES AS INT))))))));
    SET @Utilidad2 = ((@Deprec2) * (@Utililidad1));
    SET @Inversion2 = ((@Inversion1) - (@Deprec2));
    SET @IVA2 = ((@Utilidad2) * (@IVA1));
    SET @Total = ((@Utilidad2) + (@IVA2));

BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Dep_Act;

    IF @FechaReg <> @Fechahoy
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Setting the param'

        UPDATE Dep_Act 
        SET Int_Meses = ((SELECT CAST (@MESES AS INT)));

        UPDATE Dep_Act 
        SET Dbl_Depreciacion = @Deprec2;

        UPDATE Dep_Act 
        SET Dbl_Inversion = @Inversion2;

        UPDATE Dep_Act 
        SET Dbl_Margen = @Utilidad2;

        UPDATE Dep_Act 
        SET Dbl_Iva = @IVA2;

        UPDATE Dep_Act 
        SET Dbl_TotalDep = @Total;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'All good'
    END;
END;
END;
```

Running this give me this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.DEPRE, Line 4,20, 24, 25 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

And it makes `NULL` all the columns I was trying to update.

If in the variable `@FechaReg` have a `WHERE` like this:

```
@FechaReg DATETIME = (SELECT Fec_ActivoDep FROM Dep_Act WHERE Int_IdInmovilizado = 3),
```

It runs only with the stated value and calculates correctly the `DATEDIFF` and updates all the table with that value, but the other values I tried to calculate are still `NULL`

If someone can tell me if I'm using the incorrect syntax or is something I'm not declaring, I would appreciate the help, thank you

Comment: How many rows do you have in Dep_Act? If there are more than 1 row your SET statements will fail as the query you are using may return many rows, add filter or do MAX/MIN to restrict it to one rows.

Comment: I got 663 rows and 18 columns

Comment: Your SP doesn't make sense if you have so many rows, are you updating same value for all rows in dep_act? Your update statement doesn't have any kind of identifier for rows to update.

Comment: Describe the `business problem` this SP is trying to solve. It'll make it easier to make sense of it all.

Comment: I need to affect and calculate all the rows with their particulary values, all rows have their ID, If what you say is making a "loop" to count and calculate each row, I can try, but I dont know how to declare it or how to implement it

Comment: Essentially it is a depreciation table that reduces the monetary value every month @HardCode

Comment: Self join the `Dep_Act` in the `UPDATE` and there is no need to all those variables.

Comment: @Sami Can you please explain me how, i dont fully understand you

Answer (score 0):

To correct your error message just do something like this :
Instead of

```
@Inversion1 = (SELECT Dbl_MontoInv FROM Dep_Act)
```

do

```
@Inversion1 = (SELECT TOP 1 Dbl_MontoInv FROM Dep_Act)
```

I'm not sure it is what you want.
If I understand correctly, you want to update each row of your table.
You should do a big `UPDATE` and make your computations using `CASE WHEN END` and subqueries (don't forget the TOP 1)

It is quite difficult to help you without having your table schema and a good understanding of what you wanna do.

Comment: I can provide the table schema if I knew how, but essentially what I have is a table with 663 rows, with the date, value and name of when a product was bought, I need to calculate how many months had pass(every row has a different date, value and name, but Im only interest in the firts two) to calculate a depreciation table, applying the formulas they gave me

Comment: So why don't you just use a datediff in a select into another table?